# Can one make 3-column alignments with amsmath?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Align two inequalities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities)

I'd like to make an {align} with *three* columns, with an [rcl] type alignment, to typeset something like

a < b < c

a < bb < c

a < bbb < c

and so on, with all less-than symbols vertically aligned. The standard {alignat}{2} in amsmath allows me to fake an [rll] type alignment (first column
right justified, second and fourth columns left justified, with an empty third column), but it seems clumsy. I could manage with the old array environment if I did not need to add labels to each line. Is there a package to do three-column alignments directly, compatible with amsmath?

Comment: `amsmath` is designed to make typesetting high quality mathematics easy. What you're asking for typically does not look very good and is pretty uncommon.

Comment: I agree with @TH. If you want to do it nevertheless, you probably can find an answer [in this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4273/1235).

Comment: @Hendrik: Good point. Voting to close as an exact duplicate. (I note I even gave an answer in the other post...)

Comment: @Hendrik: Thanks for the link, my search missed it.

Comment: @TH: Not an exact duplicate, though, since I need equation labels, too. The best answers to that other post require manual box measurements for each instance; can't one do better, say with judiciously placed \hfil's? (I appreciate your aesthetic judgement, but I still need to solve this conundrum.)

Comment: @jvarilly: The link isn't so easy to find, indeed. `\hfill` s don't seem to help (not sure why), and the manual measurement isn't great, but equation numbers are not a problem; just use `alignat` instead of `alignat*`.