# AMS align: left aligned text/math plus multicolumn alignment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

This question is basically a combination of two previous posts: [How can I add left aligned text to an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1665) and [AMS align / Align multiple “=”, too much space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6572/2304) (the latter being my own question).

What I need is a multicolumn align, as discussed (and solved) in the second post linked above, plus a left aligned label (text and/or math), as discussed in the first post. And if possible some indent for the left aligned text would be nice. 
So, basically, an itemized list with custom text/math instead of bullets and nicely aligned equations as items...

I tried

```
\begin{flalign}
 &aaaa & bbb &= cccccc && = d\\    &ee & f &= g && = hh
\end{flalign}
```

and that gives me the left aligned labels and the other stuff aligned at the equal signs. But the third column is flushed all the way to the right. I guess that's the feature of `flalign`. Or am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

So: how can I get the desired format? Is there a way to combine `flalign` and `alignat`? Or are there other ways to do this? (I guess tables, etc. wouldn't really work here).

Comment: I'm preeeetty sure all these "alignment environments" *are* `\halign`s under the hood (read: tables).

Comment: Related Question: [Left-aligned text inside an equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59995/left-aligned-text-inside-an-equation).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \noindent\hrulefill
    \begin{flalign*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \rlap{aaaa}\\    \rlap{ee}
    \end{aligned} 
    &&\arraycolsep=1.4pt
    \begin{array}{rll}
    bbb &= cccccc &= d\\[\jot]
    f   &= g      &= hh   
    \end{array} 
    &&
    \begin{aligned}
    \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\\   \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
    \end{aligned} 
    \end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not bad, but the _horizontal_ alignment is not OK. I guess you need some struts. (And I think the OP really wants _left_ aligned labels; this also comes out if you compile his code.)

Comment: @Hendrik: thanks, the `\jot` was missing ...

Answer (score 0):

Since `alignat` allows you to specify the spacing, what about:

```
\begin{alignat}
 &aaaa \qquad\qquad& bbb &= cccccc && = d\\
 &ee & f &= g && = hh
\end{alignat}
```

Not perfect (the labels are not left flushed) but...

Another solution is to replace the normal equation numbering by your labels:

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
\tag*{aaaa}   bbb &= cccccc && = d\\
\tag*{ee}   f &= g && = hh
\end{alignat}
```

EDIT: note that the latest solution requires to pass the `leqno` option to the `amsmath` package...