# Left-aligned text inside an equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Inside an equation-like environment, I'd like to have some text that is aligned to the left margin of the text block, something like `\intertext`, but in the same line as the equation

Something like this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\newcommand*{\midmathskip}{\hskip0.5\displaywidth\hskip-0.5\totwidth@}
\newcommand*{\lefttext}[1]{\llap{\rlap{#1}\midmathskip}}

\begin{align}
\lefttext{and similarly}
 \hphantom{nn-nn}
 \mathllap{hwnn} &= H+hw. \\
\lefttext{Thus}
 nn-nn &= 1.
\end{align}
```

of course, the `\hphantom` and `\mathllap` are just hacks to make it look right in this case, but I'm looking for something that would work in a gather environment too. `flalign` could help, for it alters the alignment of the equations (they are not in the center of the text block any more), and it doesn't help with `gather` anyway.

As a bonus, it would also be nice if it worked with `aligned` and `alignedat`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! (I think we know each other from `comp.text.tex`.) One of my guidelines is that if something is difficult to obtain with TeX/LaTeX, then it's probably bad typography. This is the case, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I asked the same question in comp.text.tex. Maybe you are right and it's bad typography, but it's used in at least [one book](http://books.google.es/books?id=XehUpGiM6FIC&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q&f=false), which I'm trying to reproduce, and I don't think it looks bad.

Comment: Sorry, but it *does* look bad to me. I can see page 128; that lonely "Put" had better be in a line of its own and my feeling is that equation 56 is *never* referenced, so it should be simply in line or it should be a parenthetical addition to equation 55.

Comment: @egreg Well, yes, I agree on the "Put", and some other cases look weird too, but equation 56 is referenced in pages 129 and 130 at least (and all potentially useful equations should have a number, anyway, although they not always do in this book).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [AMS align: Left aligned text/math plus multicolumn align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/ams-align-left-aligned-text-math-plus-multicolumn-align).

Comment: @PeterGrill The problem there is slightly different and the solution is *ad hoc* for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variant, which works with math-environments which understand `\tag`. Together with the class-option `leqno` it doesn't work thou. I learned this approach from Philipp Stephani. It works the same way as `amsmath`s intertext, but puts the text on the same line as the equation.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\makeatletter
\newif\if@gather@prefix 
\preto\place@tag@gather{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@ 
    \kern-\gdisplaywidth@ 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\gdisplaywidth@ 
  \fi\fi 
} 
\appto\place@tag@gather{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@\else 
    \kern-\displaywidth 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth 
  \fi\fi 
  \global\@gather@prefixfalse 
} 
\preto\place@tag{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@ 
    \kern-\gdisplaywidth@ 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth@ 
  \fi\fi 
} 
\appto\place@tag{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@\else 
    \kern-\displaywidth 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth 
  \fi\fi 
  \global\@gather@prefixfalse 
} 
\newcommand*{\beforetext}[1]{% 
  \ifmeasuring@\else
  \gdef\gather@prefix{#1}% 
  \global\@gather@prefixtrue 
  \fi
} 
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \label{eq:1}
  \beforetext{and similary} hwnn &= H+hw\\
  \beforetext{Thus} nn-nn &=1.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

Comment: This solution would be easier to use, but it seems the `\beforetext` is disabled along with the numbering when `\notag` or the starred environments are used. And worse, the text is saved and used in a following equation.

Comment: It was easy to fix, see my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what you referred to for page 136:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtool,lipsum}
\newcommand{\lefttext}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\hbar\omega\eta\bar{\eta} 
  &= (2m)^{-1}(p+im\omega q)(p-im\omega q)\\
  &=(2m)^{-1}[p^{2}+m^{2}\omega^{2}q^{2}+im\omega(qp-pq)]\\
  &=H-\yfrac{1}{2}\hbar\omega 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\vspace{\glueexpr-\baselineskip-\belowdisplayskip-\jot\relax}
\begin{flalign}
&\lefttext{and similarly}&  \hbar\omega\bar{\eta}\eta &= H+\tfrac{1}{2}\hbar\omega. &&\\
&\lefttext{Thus}& \bar{\eta}\eta-\eta\bar{\eta} &= 1.
\end{flalign}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{flalign}
&\lefttext{Here}&\mathclap{a long equation} &&\\
&\lefttext{whence}&\mathclap{short} &&
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

We have to play a bit with the vertical spacing because two different environments must go one after another. Expect some manual intervention to fix cases like this (the space between equations 1 and 2 is not really precise).

The important aspect for you is the `flalign` environment. We provide two mock groups at start and end, with zero width, so the middle group will be effectively centered.

[image]

I've added a strategy for emulating `gather`:

```
\begin{flalign}
&\lefttext{Here}&\mathclap{a long equation} &&\\
&\lefttext{whence}&\mathclap{short} &&
\end{flalign}
```

Load `mathtools` for `\mathclap`. It will be up to you avoiding overlaps.

Comment: Of course, a zero-width box fixes the alignment issue of `flalign`, but still there's the problem with `gather` (and the vertical spacing is a nuisance, as you say). Thanks!

Comment: @Jellby I've added how to emulate `gather`. For the vertical spacing, there's little to do other than hoping that consecutive different environments don't appear often. There's no real clue for aligning both those above in only one environment. However, it seems that taking away also `\jot` fixes the issue.

Comment: Nice! My LaTeX skills are a bit rusty... Any chance something could be done for `aligned` and `alignedat`?

Comment: @Jellby I don't think so. Only `flalign` does what you want. However, you might give a look at the `IEEEeqnarray` environment provided by the IEEE classes. My support of bad typography ends here. ;-)

Comment: And since `align` and friends can be nested inside `gather` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60566/15647)), the vertical spacing issue can be fixed that way too.

Answer (score 3):

Just patching `\math@cr@@@align` I could make Peter Breitfeld's solution to work as I needed. Now it works with `align`, `gather`, with and without equation numbers, and with some tricks even with `aligned`! It doesn't work with `equation`, but that can be replaced with `gather`.

I had to copy the definition from `amsmath.sty`, just to include the `\if@gather@prefix\tag@true\fi`, which must go after the `\omit` (I don't know if there's an easier way to patch it).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox} 

\makeatletter
\newif\if@gather@prefix 
\preto\place@tag@gather{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@ 
    \kern-\gdisplaywidth@ 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\gdisplaywidth@ 
  \fi\fi 
} 
\appto\place@tag@gather{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@\else 
    \kern-\displaywidth 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth 
  \fi\fi 
  \global\@gather@prefixfalse 
} 
\preto\place@tag{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@ 
    \kern-\gdisplaywidth@ 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth@ 
  \fi\fi 
} 
\appto\place@tag{% 
  \if@gather@prefix\iftagsleft@\else 
    \kern-\displaywidth 
    \rlap{\gather@prefix}% 
    \kern\displaywidth 
  \fi\fi 
  \global\@gather@prefixfalse 
} 
\def\math@cr@@@align{%
  \ifst@rred\nonumber\fi
  \if@eqnsw \global\tag@true \fi
  \global\advance\row@\@ne
  \add@amps\maxfields@
  \omit
  \kern-\alignsep@
  \if@gather@prefix\tag@true\fi
  \iftag@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign\strut@{\make@display@tag}}%
    \place@tag
  \fi
  \ifst@rred\else\global\@eqnswtrue\fi
  \global\lineht@\z@
  \cr
}
\newcommand*{\beforetext}[1]{% 
  \ifmeasuring@\else
  \gdef\gather@prefix{#1}% 
  \global\@gather@prefixtrue 
  \fi
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

align
\begin{align}
  \beforetext{and similary} hwnn &= H+hw\\
  \beforetext{Thus} nn-nn &=1.
\end{align}

align*
\begin{align*}
  \beforetext{and similary} hwnn &= H+hw\\
  \beforetext{Thus} nn-nn &=1.
\end{align*}

gather (\textbackslash notag on the first line)
\begin{gather}
  \beforetext{and similary} hwnn = H+hw \notag \\
  \beforetext{Thus} nn-nn =1.
\end{gather}

aligned
\begin{gather}
  \beforetext{$\displaystyle\begin{aligned}&\!\text{and similarly}\\&\!\text{Thus}\end{aligned}$}
  \begin{aligned}
    hwnn &= H+hw\\
    nn-nn &=1.
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really nice improvement of my solution (+1). I found the the starred version needs a tag even an empty one like `\tag*{\null}` to work, but couldn't find how to apply it automatically.