# How to center equations inside flalign

Tags: amsmath, alignment, flalign

I have noticed that, for multiple single-column lines, `flalign` produces right-aligned formulas, while other alignment environments provided by [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) produce center-aligned formulas. See the MWE below.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a) \\
a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{gather*}

\begin{flalign*}
\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a) \\
a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

`amsmath`’s [user’s guide](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf#section.3.6) does not explain this behavior.

How do I center-align formulas in `flalign`?

Note that I do not want to align lines at, for instance, the equal sign. I want formulas to be centered relative to the page’s full body width, and I need to achieve this using `flalign` (I’m doing [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61340/301662)).

Comment: like all ams alignments flalign alternates between right and left alignment and as you have no & you get right alignment. specifying flalign but giving no alignment points is basically user error

Comment: use gather* and set `\mathindent` to zero

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried putting `&&` before and after the formulas of each line inside `flalign` but the result is the same: right-aligned formulas.

Comment: yes naturally, if you put `&&` before the formula you have two empty columns and the formula in column 3 so again right aligned

Comment: the only ams multi line display that centers is `gather` as that does no alignment, so the answer here is to use `gather`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The issue is that when using `gather` I cannot type left-aligned text beside and on the same line as the formulas, as explained [here][1]. That is my end goal, but with center-aligned formulas.


  [1] https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61340/301662

Comment: Is there a reason for your apparent refusal, or reluctance, to use `&` for the purpose of setting alignment points?

Comment: maybe you should ask a question about that, as as written there is no answer other than use gather. _all_ alignment environments: align, aligned, flalign, split, ... have right alignment in odd columns and left alignment in even

Comment: @Mico Yes. The formulas I’m working with have a lot of text and no specific anchor point for alignment that looks good (as is the case with equations), so having them centered would be more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @donjuardo - In that case, you should follow David Carlisle's earlier advice, which is to `gather` and `gather*` environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `\nathclap` (mathtools), but `gather` is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a) \\
a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{gather*}

\begin{flalign*}
&& \mathclap{\int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a)}  &&\\
&& \mathclap{a^2 = b^2 + c^2} &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]