# How to reduce hspace between columns in align environment

Tags: spacing, align

With the following MWE, I have 2 columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
4   &= 4 && \text{yes}\\
0   &= 0 && \text{no}\\
1+1 &= 2 && \text{maybe}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But I would like to control the hspace between the 2 columns, possibly, with only one command call for the whole `align`, rather than one for each line.

Comment: You could use an `array` environment instead and then `{rl@{\quad}l}` for the column specificator.

Comment: Have you seen this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361275/latex-ams-align-align-multiple-too-much-space ? it at least is able to reduce the space between the first 3 columns (your equations) and the second column, where you put the text.

Comment: @Ronny The question is also on TeX.SX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/ams-align-align-multiple-too-much-space

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `alignat` environment, that gives full control over the alignment:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
4   &= 4\qquad && \text{yes}\\
0   &= 0\qquad && \text{no}\\
1+1 &= 2\qquad && \text{maybe}
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Actually only the widest entry in the second column needs the padding, but it's easier to specify it on each one.

The "2" refers to the number of "left hand side-right hand side" groups you need.

A more general solution is to define a new environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\royalignsep@
\def\royalign@preamble{%
   &\hfil
    \strut@
    \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \tabskip\z@skip
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\royalignsep@
}
\NewEnviron{royalign}[1]{%
  \royalignsep@=#1\let\align@preamble=\royalign@preamble
  \begin{align}\BODY\end{align}}
\NewEnviron{royalign*}[1]{%
  \royalignsep@=#1\let\align@preamble=\royalign@preamble
  \begin{align*}\BODY\end{align*}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{royalign*}{1cm}
4   &= 4 & 1+3+5 &= 9\\
0   &= 0 & 2+1   &= 3\\
1+1 &= 2 & 1     &= 1
\end{royalign*}
\end{document}
```

You have both `royalign` and `royalign*`; you can check that the spacing is exactly what you specify in the argument.

Comment: yes, this solution is good for the situation "one column of equations + one column of text". But for two column of equations, this is not optimal, since one has to put a hspace which depends on the largest entry of the right hand side terms of the left hand side column. I would prefer to say " i want 1 cm between the 2 columns of equations", independently of their content. Am i clear ?

Comment: by the way, i don't see any influence of the  parameter "2"...

Comment: @nicolasroy See edit.

Comment: My apologize for being so late in answering. Thanks for the solution, it works very well. Could you just tell me, why you use `\NewEnviron` ? What does it bring in contrast to `\newenvironment{royalign}{\royalignsep@ ... \begin{align}}{\end{align}}`

Comment: @nicolasroy It's the usual problem about `align`, where TeX has to "see" the precise sequence of tokens `\end{align}` in order to decide when the environment ends, since it has to collect the contents and measure it. Actually, `\NewEnviron` is inspired by `amsmath`'s method: it collects the environments contents and, in this case, it passes it to `align`.

Comment: A detail: with your code, the bloc of equations is no more horizontally centered. Compare the equations of your solution (in the edit) for `\begin{royalign*}{1cm}...`  and for `\begin{align*}{3}`

Comment: Sorry: this would need to redesign completely the computations that `amsmath` performs. At least as far as I can see.

Comment: ok. No problem. Thanks a lot for the solution anyway.

Answer (score 3):

use the old `xalignat` environment if it could be left aligned

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{xalignat*}
4   &= 4 && \text{yes}\\
0   &= 0 && \text{no}\\
1+1 &= 2 && \text{maybe}
\end{xalignat*}
\end{document}
```