# aligning equals as well as plus signs

Tags: align

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/ams-align-align-multiple-too-much-space) question we know that aligning the equal signs in

```
A = B = C
D = E = F
```

is done by using `alignat`, not `align`.

If we have instead

```
A = W + M = C
B = i + \iota = D
```

how can the equal signs as well as the `+` signs be aligned?

Comment: Refer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75108/how-to-edit-the-linear-programming-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important rule for all `*align*` environments is `rlrlrlrl…`, meaning that alternating columns are left-, right-, left-, right-, …-aligned.

Such basic question as you posted can be easily written in many ways (#1 = #2, #3 = #4):

### Code (MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{alignat*}{3} % #1
A & = W & {}+{} & M     && = C \\
B & = i & {}+{} & \iota && = D
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{3} % #2
A & = W && {} + M     && = C \\
B & = i && {} + \iota && = D
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{3} % #3
A & ={} & W +{} & &     M & = C \\
B & =   & i +{} & & \iota & = D
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{3} % #4
A & ={} & W & +{} &     M & = C \\
B & =   & i & +{} & \iota & = D
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Left-aligned (#1 and #2)

[image: left aligned (#1 and #2)]

#### Right-aligned (#3 and #4)

[image: right aligned (#3 and #4)]

Comment: Is there any center-aligned option?