# alignat makes 3 good alignments and 1 bad

Tags: amsmath, align, matrices

I'm having a problem with the `alignat` environment. This code:

```
\begin{alignat*}{9}
&X_{12}&+X_{13}&       &       &       &       &       &       &        &=1 \\
&      & X_{13}&+X_{23}&       &       &-X_{35}&       &       &        &=0 \\
&X_{12}&       &-X_{23}&-X_{24}&-X_{25}&       &       &       &        &=0 \\
&      &       &       & X_{24}&       &       &-X_{45}&-X_{46}&        &=0 \\
&      &       &       &       & X_{25}&+X_{35}&+X_{45}&       &-X_{56} &=0 \\
&      &       &       &       &       &       &       & X_{46}&+X_{56} &=1 \\
\end{alignat*}
```

produces this matrix:

[image: matrix image]

I don't understand why the `X_{25}` doesn't align, when `X_{13}`, `X_{24}` and `X_{46}` does. Can anybody help me understand this, and even better, how to fix it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: For understanding: `align`-type environments are for aligning *equations* which consist of a *left* and a *right* part, like this: *left* `&` *right* `&` *next equation...*. So the `&` signs you used have different meanings to the `align` environment, and your formula parts are interpreted, in turn, as left or right parts, and aligned accordingly (also note that every second operator has different spacing).

Comment: Related answer: [aligning equals as well as plus signs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75323/16595)

Answer (score 11):

`alignat` builds alternatively right and left aligned columns; your `X_{25}` falls in an even numbered column.

Thus this is not the best way to typeset these equations, because the spacing around the operation signs is uneven; better using an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} % for extended syntax in array

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{18}{@{}>{{}}l<{{}}@{}}}
X_{12}&+&X_{13}& &      & &      & &      & &      & &      & &      & &      &=1 \\
      & &X_{13}&+&X_{23}& &      & &      &-&X_{35}& &      & &      & &      &=0 \\
X_{12}& &      &-&X_{23}&-&X_{24}&-&X_{25}& &      & &      & &      & &      &=0 \\
      & &      & &      & &X_{24}& &      & &      &-&X_{45}&-&X_{46}& &      &=0 \\
      & &      & &      & &      & &X_{25}&+&X_{35}&+&X_{45}& &      &-&X_{56}&=0 \\
      & &      & &      & &      & &      & &      & &      & &X_{46}&+&X_{56}&=1 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

I build 18 columns, each left aligned; each will become `${}#{}$\hfil`, where `#` denotes the actual cell entry. So if the entry is an operation symbol, say `+`, `${}+{}$` will leave the correct spacing around `+`. In case it's `X_{12}` the empty groups do nothing.

[image]

A different solution is with `systeme`; the setup is not much more complicated than as above, although it requires doing some substitutions; however the input is quite clearer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\syssubstitute{%
  {x_1}{X_{12}}%
  {x_2}{X_{13}}%
  {x_3}{X_{23}}%
  {x_4}{X_{24}}%
  {x_5}{X_{25}}%
  {x_6}{X_{35}}%
  {x_7}{X_{45}}%
  {x_8}{X_{46}}%
  {x_9}{X_{56}}%
}
\sysdelim..
\systeme{
x_1+x_2                            =1,
    x_2+x_3        -x_6            =0,
x_1    -x_3-x_4-x_5                =0,
            x_4        -x_7-x_8    =0,
                x_5+x_6+x_7    -x_9=0,
                            x_8+x_9=1
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 2017

The new `autoaligne` package allows for a different solution. Unfortunately, empty slots should be denoted by `+` with no following space, but with some stretch we can also get a good alignment in the input: the trick is to locally set the space to an ignored character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\catcode` =9 % ignore spaces
\autoaligne{%
  X_{12}+X_{13}+      +      +      +      +      +      +      =1 \\%
        +X_{13}+X_{23}+      +      -X_{35}+      +      +      =0 \\%
  X_{12}+      -X_{23}-X_{24}-X_{25}+      +      +      +      =0 \\%
        +      +      +X_{24}+      +      -X_{45}-X_{46}+      =0 \\%
        +      +      +      +X_{25}+X_{35}+X_{45}+      -X_{56}=0 \\%
        +      +      +      +      +      +      +X_{46}+X_{56}=1
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The environment `alignat` is intended for aligning several equation systems on a line:

```
abc = def   ghi = jkl
  m = n       o = p
```

Therefore there are two alignments per system, the equal sign in the middle and in-between two systems:

```
abc &= def & ghi &= jkl \\
m   &= n   &   o &= p \\
```

The part left from the equal sign is right justified, the part afterwards left justified.
In your case you probably want right justification, thus you need two `&&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{9}
X_{12}&&{}+X_{13}&&         &&         &&         &&         &&         &&         &&          &=1 \\
      && X_{13}  &&{}+X_{23}&&         &&         &&{}-X_{35}&&         &&         &&          &=0 \\
X_{12}&&         &&{}-X_{23}&&{}-X_{24}&&{}-X_{25}&&         &&         &&         &&          &=0 \\
      &&         &&         && X_{24}  &&         &&         &&{}-X_{45}&&{}-X_{46}&&          &=0 \\
      &&         &&         &&         && X_{25}  &&{}+X_{35}&&{}+X_{45}&&         &&{}-X_{56} &=0 \\
      &&         &&         &&         &&         &&         &&         && X_{46}  &&{}+X_{56} &=1 \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

At some places I have also added an empty math subformula `{}` in front of `+` or `-` right after `&`. This way TeX knows that `+` and `-` should be set as binary operators (between `{}` and `X`) and the spacing is better.

Answer (score 6):

`$X_{25}$`is left-aligned with `$-X_{25}$`, that's what you asked for in your environment. I suggest you add alignment tabs around each `+`and `-`symbol as well, to achieve the visual effect you want.

Please note that `$X_{24}$` is correctly aligned, because that column is right-aligned.
The rule in that environment is :

- first column right-aligned
- second column left-aligned
- ...
- fifth column (`X_{24}`) right-aligned, hence correct in your sense
- sixth column (`X_{25}`) left-aligned
- etc