# Subequations inside align result in too wide equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, subequations

I want to create subequations and allign them such that nice 'inquality constraints' arise. My current code:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a & \le b & \le c \label{eq:constr1}\\
d & \le effff & \le f \label{eq:constr1}\\
\end{align}
\label{eq:constr}%
\end{subequations}
```

The result in PDF is a much too large distance between "`b` and `c`" and "`efffff` and `f`". I would like to have `\le` exactly below eachother. Have `b` and `effff` centered between those. Finally `a` and `d` should be right aligned to the `\le` and `c` and `f` should be left aligned to the `\le`.

Comment: Leave the second `&` out. The columns in `align` (and family) are `rlrlrl…` aligned. Or use `aligned` and `a & \le b && \le c`.

Comment: Also, don't use the same `\label` ("eq:constr1") more than once.

Comment: … or (“centering for b and e”) use simply `a \le b & \le c` (i.e. leave the first `&` out). Related: [`alignat` examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75323/16595), [more complex case of alignments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75108/16595)

Comment: In reality b and e are strings of unequal length, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @Martijn Well, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) could help out and maybe an image of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Edited, not MWE, but hosuld be clear now. Unfortunatly I cannot upload a simple picture.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the middle column to be centered than you need to either resort to using a `\makebox` to reserve enough width for that column, which requires knowing what the widest element is beforehand, or to use an `array`:

[image]

### Notes

- The `alignat` provides *pairs* of `rl` aligned equations. Since we want the third column to be `l`eft aligned, we need to use a `&&` to skip past the prior column that would have been `r`ight aligned.
- For the `array` solution we need to use `{}` to make the inequality symbols be treated as relational operators, similar to the difference in spacing of `$-x$` and `${}-x$`.
- [The `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) was used for the `\widthof{}` macro, so is only required for the `alignat` solution.
- As Qrrbrbirlbel commented, you could make use of [the `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) and incorporate the required `{}` into the column specification, as shown in the last example in the code below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\Widest}{effff}%
\newcommand*{\WideAs}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\Widest$}][c]{$#1$}}%
\begin{document}\noindent
You can use \verb|alignat|:
%
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    a & \le \WideAs{b}     && \le c \\
    d & \le \WideAs{effff} && \le f 
\end{alignat*}
%
Or use \verb|array|:
%
\[\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}
    a \le {}& b     &{} \le c \\
    d \le {}& effff &{} \le f 
\end{array}\]
%
Alternatively using the \verb|array| package:
\[\begin{array}{r<{{}}@{}c@{}>{{}}l}
    a \le & b     & \le c \\
    d \le & effff & \le f 
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `{r<{{}}@{}c@{}>{{}}l}` (`array` package) to mimic the behavior of `*align*` and wouldn’t have to manually insert `{}`. And you might point out that `alignat` does provide equation numbers quite easier than `array`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks, incorporated that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! The equations however are compressed in height as would normally don for using $some-equation$. What would be a solution to keep the proper full size?

Comment: @Martijn: I do not know why you think the equations are compressed. The solutions here produce the correct display mode math spacing. If you are using inline math (as is the case `$some-equation$`, then the equations are compressed in order to not alter the interline spacing of a paragraph.

Comment: If you still think they are compressed I would recommend you post a follow up question and be sure to include a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates this compression. It should start with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi Peter, my department at the university provides a documentclass with a lot of build in options to keep publications uniform. Unfortunatly I can therefor not provide a MWE with a documentclass.

I can also not upload a picture to show you the difference between the example in my original post and the result I get now. Hopefully I can do so in the future with more credits.

Comment: Well then I believe that the problem lies in your custom document class. You can upload an image picture icon if you edit your question. Then just remove the leading `!` and someone with more rep will put the `!` back in and the image will be displayed.