# Centering \vdots in a system of many equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, align, horizontal-alignment

I have a system of equations with an arbitrary number of equations (*k*). I'd like to use `\vdots` to compactly describe the system, like so:

```
\begin{align*}
  R(-1) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-1) \\
  R(-2) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-2) \\
        &\vdots                    \\
  R(-k) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-k)
\end{align*}
```

[image: LaTeX output of above code with only minimal.cls and amsmath.sty]

I'd like the dots, however, to be centered with `=` or the entire equation. Is there an elegant way of centering a column or row with AMSMath? I'm currently using an unholy combination of whitespace operators (`\;` `\,` etc.) to get the job done.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  R(-1) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-1) \\
  R(-2) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-2) \\
        &\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\vdots}} \\
  R(-k) &= \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-k)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me to it … anyhow, in case there is a wish to avoid using the calc package, here is my version: `\setbox0\hbox{=}\mathrel{\makebox[\wd0]{\hfil\vdots\hfil}}`.

Comment: I like it! I had been looking at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities/4283#4283), but I didn't like the need for all the temporary width definitions.  `\widthof` is a great new tool for me. I'll leave the question open for a bit longer, but I think this is the answer.

Comment: @Harald the \hfil are not needed

Comment: You're right; instead of `\makebox[\wd0]` I had `\hbox to \wd0` and then I forgot to remove the `\hfil` after I changed it.

Answer (score 52):

Consider the package `mathtools`, which provides several corrections for and additions to `amsmath`.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

It also provides a comfortable solution for your problem. You can even choose between a normal (`\vdotswithin`) and a short (`\shortvdotswithin`) distance.

```
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  & = c \\
  \shortvdotswithin{=}
  & = d
\end{align*}
```

The result convinces.

[image: Example showing vdotswithin and shortvdotswithin]

More details can be found in the documentation of the package, section "Centered `\vdots`", where also the example above is taken from.

Comment: This solution worked for me while Herbert's led to a misalignement, I'm not sure why.

Comment: this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option (not very popular among TeXans):

```
\begin{eqnarray}
  R(-1) &=& \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-1) \\
  R(-2) &=& \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-2) \\
        &\vdots& \\
  R(-k) &=& \sum_{i=1}^m A(i)R(i-k)
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: the spacing is lousy in an `eqnarray` environment. You can it improve wit `\arraycolsep=1.4pt`

Comment: Yes, I know... this is why I said it is not a popular option...