# Centering in the \align* environment

Tags: amsmath, align

I'm using the `\align*` environment from the `amsmath` package.  How can I center one of the lines inside the environment?

In the following example, I want to the `\vdots` to be centered, instead of awkwardly aligned with the `b` above it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& a = (a_1, a_2) \\
& b = (b_1, b_2) \\
& \vdots \\
& z = (z_1, z_2)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want it centered, or under the equal sign?

Comment: You're misusing `align`: try ``a &= (a_1,a_2) \\`` and similarly for the other lines; then ``& \mathrel{\:\vdots} \\`` will be aligned under the equals signs.

Comment: or since you don't seem to be aligning anything, perhaps gather: `\begin{gather*}
 a = (a_1, a_2) \ b = (b_1, b_2) \ \vdots \ z = (z_1, z_2)
\end{gather*}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 a &= (a_1, a_2) \\
 b &= (b_1, b_2) \\
 &\phantom{b=\,} \vdots \\
 z &= (z_1, z_2)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This question is similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/), but to complete this page, I will add a similar answer here.

If you want to *center the points unter the equal signs*, then you should consider the package `mathtools`, which provides several corrections for and additions to `amsmath`.

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

It also provides a comfortable solution for your problem. You can even choose between a normal (`\vdotswithin`) and a short (`\shortvdotswithin`) distance.

```
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  & \vdotswithin{=} \\
  & = c \\
  \shortvdotswithin{=}
  & = d
\end{align*}
```

The result convinces.

[image: Example showing vdotswithin and shortvdotswithin]

More details can be found in the documentation of the package, section "Centered \vdots", where also the example above is taken from.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure there are plenty of ways of doing this. One of which would be to use `\ooalign`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & a = (a_1, a_2) \\
  & b = (b_1, b_2) \\
  & \vdots \\
  & z = (z_1, z_2)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  a &= (a_1, a_2) \\
  b &= (b_1, b_2) \\
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \vphantom{$\vdots$}% For height
    \ooalign{\phantom{$a=(a_1, a_2)$}\cr\hss$\vdots$\hss}}% Centered \vdots
    \phantom{a}% For placement
      & \\
  z &= (z_1, z_2)
\end{align*}
\end{document}​
```

See [this answer for a quick course on `\ooalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22375/5764).