# centering a part of an equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am using `\vdots` in my equation, and I need it to be centered. As shown in the figure it is automatically left indented. I am not able to bring the dots to the center. I am providing MWE also.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}


\usepackage{graphicx,cite,epsfig,amssymb,amsmath,endnotes,algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   &X_{1} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \nonumber \,,\\
  &X_{2} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \nonumber \,,\\
 \vdots \nonumber
 \\&X_{A-1} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \nonumber\,, \\
&X_{A} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \nonumber \,, \\
  &X \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
  \end{align} 

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load `epsfig`, it's an obsolete package. Don't use `\left` and `\right` in that context: it just makes the formula worse. I never leave space before commas in math.

Comment: I would define a macro to handle your use of `\mathcal{N}(...)`. For example, `\newcommand{\nat}[1]{\mathcal{N}(#1)}` and then use `\nat{A}`, `\nat{B}`, ... See [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).

Comment: Since it's not clear which horizontal alignment the OP is after, it's only 50% duplicate of [Centering `\vdots` in a system of many equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7650/5764).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 1. Aligned with `\rightarrow`

You can align it with the `\rightarrow` as such:

[image]

### Notes:

- You can use `align*` so that you don't need to add `\nonumber` to each line.
- Usually you would not want to put the alignment at the beginning of the first term, so I have moved it to be *before* the `\rightarrow`.

---

### 2. Centered with `\rightarrow`:

A better solution is to use `\makebox` to get the `vdots` centered within the space of the `\rightarrow`:

[image]

### Notes:

- This requires the use of [the `calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc).
- This has the benefit that no manual guessing of spacing is required. Hence, this solution can easily be adapted to other cases.

### 3. Centered with `\rightarrow` (with other enhancements)

I have provided another version which:

1. Incorporates **Werner**'s recommendation of using [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/consistent-typography) by defining a `\nat` macro.
2. Incorporates **egreg**'s recommendation to eliminate the space prior to the comma.

This yields:

[image]

---

### Code: aligned with `\rightarrow`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   X_{1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \nonumber \,,\\
  X_{2} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \nonumber \,,\\
 &\vdots \nonumber
 \\X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \nonumber\,, \\
X_{A} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \nonumber \,, \\
  X &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
  \end{align} 

\begin{align*}
   X_{1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \,,\\
  X_{2} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \,,\\
 &\vdots \nonumber
 \\X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \,, \\
X_{A} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \,, \\
  X &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
  \end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

### Code: centered with `\rightarrow`

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   X_{1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \,,\\
  X_{2} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \,,\\
 &\makebox[\widthof{${}\rightarrow{}$}][c]{\vdots}
 \\X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \,, \\
X_{A} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \,, \\
  X &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
  \end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

### 3. Code: centered with `\rightarrow` (with other enhancements)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\nat}[1]{\mathcal{N}(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     X_{1} &\rightarrow \nat{A}, \\
     X_{2} &\rightarrow \nat{B}, \\
           &\makebox[\widthof{${}\rightarrow{}$}][c]{\vdots} \\
   X_{A-1} &\rightarrow \nat{C}, \\
     X_{A} &\rightarrow \nat{D}, \\
         X &\rightarrow \nat{E}.
  \end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or, without packages, `\mathrel{\ooalign{\hphantom{$\rightarrow$}\cr\hfil\vdots\hfil\cr}}`. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this. Notice the additionally needed package `mathtools`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   X_{1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \nonumber \,,\\ 
   X_{2} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \nonumber \,,\\ 
       &\,\mathclap{\phantom{\rightarrow}\vdots} \nonumber\\ 
   X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \nonumber\,, \\ 
   X_{A} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \nonumber \,, \\ 
   X &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
\end{align} 

\end{document} 
\end{document}
```

The construction `\,\mathclap{\phantom{\rightarrow}\vdots}` is a trick to make `\vdots` center with respect to the width of `\rightarrow`. As well, I consider the alignment by the arrows to be more proper here. (As @egreg correctly points out, I should have used a larger space `\;` here. However, this smaller one seems to work well because `\rightarrow` is an assymetric symbol.)

Comment: The right spacing is `\;` (a thick space)

Comment: @egreg that's true, however, this seems to fit well since `\rightarrow` is assymetric.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation on the above:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
X_{1}     & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right)  \,,\\ 
  X_{2}   & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right)  \,,\\ 
          &  \mspace{10mu}\vdots  \\ 
  X_{A-1} & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \,, \\ 
  X_{A}   & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right)  \,, \\ 
  X       & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
    \end{split}
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `\vdotswithin` command from the `mathtools` package, as it was designed exactly for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X_{1}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(A), \\ 
X_{2}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(B), \\ 
        & \vdotswithin{\rightarrow} \\ 
X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(C), \\ 
X_{A}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(D), \\ 
X       &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(E).
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image: align using <code>/vdotswithin</code>]

Alternatively, for less vertical space above and below the dots, use `\shortvdotswithin`.  Be careful *not* to put `\\` at the end of the line containing `\shortvdotswithin`, and you don't need the `&` on that line either:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X_{1}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(A), \\ 
X_{2}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(B), \\ 
        \shortvdotswithin{\rightarrow}
X_{A-1} &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(C), \\ 
X_{A}   &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(D), \\ 
X       &\rightarrow\mathcal{N}(E).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: align using <code>\shortvdotswithin</code>]

These solutions come from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67196/21053) provided by [Thomas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17127/thomas).

Furthermore, since the question stated "I need it to be centered" and not "I need the `\vdots` to be aligned with the arrows", the answer to a literal reading of the question would be to use the `gather` environment, which centres all of its equations and doesn't take `&`:  (Use the starred version for no numbering.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
X_{1}  \rightarrow\mathcal{N}(A) ,\\ 
X_{2}  \rightarrow\mathcal{N}(B) ,\\ 
        \vdots  \\ 
X_{A-1} \rightarrow\mathcal{N}(C) , \\ 
X_{A}   \rightarrow\mathcal{N}(D) , \\ 
X       \rightarrow\mathcal{N}(E).
\end{gather*} 
\end{document}
```

[image: gather]

EDIT:  I've now uploaded the pictures above, but they're not cropped properly....

Answer (score 0):

This aligns the `\rightarrow`s and the `\vdots`:

```
\begin{align}
  X_{1}  & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(A\right) \nonumber \,,\\
  X_{2}  & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(B\right) \nonumber \,,\\
         & \ \ \vdots \nonumber \\
  X_{A-1}&  \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(C\right) \nonumber\,, \\
  X_{A}  & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(D\right) \nonumber \,, \\
  X      & \rightarrow\mathcal{N}\left(E\right)\,.
\end{align}
```

Your `LaTeX` source will be much easier for you and other people to read if you align the align symbols.

The two forced blank spaces on the `\vdots` line are a bit of a hack.