# Centering \vdots in a system of many equations and aligning the equations to the opening brace

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I have a problem similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/centering-vdots-in-a-system-of-many-equations) question.

I want to typeset `k` equations with the horizontal `\dots` and the `\vdots` aligned. The problem is that I want the equations to be aligned to the opening brace.

For example the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace %
\begin{split}
    a + b + &\dots + c = d                                    \\
    a + b + &\dots + c = d                                    \\
            &\setbox0\hbox{=}\mathrel{\makebox[\wd0]{\vdots}} \\
    aaaaaaa + b + &\dots + c = d
\end{split} %
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

As you can see the first two equations start far from the brace. So I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace %
\begin{split}
    &a + b + &\dots + c = d                                    \\
    &a + b + &\dots + c = d                                    \\
    &        &\setbox0\hbox{=}\mathrel{\makebox[\wd0]{\vdots}} \\
    &aaaaaaa + b + &\dots + c = d
\end{split} %
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

That yields what I want, but the vertical dots are not centered under the horizontal dots:

[image]

How can I obtain the alignment as in the second image but with the vertical dots aligned as in the first example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case `split` is not the best choice; rather use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{@{} l<{{}} @{} l @{}}
a + b +       &\dots + c = d                       \\
a + b +       &\dots + c = d                       \\
              &\sbox0{\dots}\makebox[\wd0]{\vdots} \\
aaaaaaa + b + &\dots + c = d
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With the addition of `<{{}}` an empty object is inserted so that the spacing around the operation symbols is correct.

[image]

You can also simplify the input by adding another alignment point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace  
\begin{array}{@{} l<{{}} @{} c @{} >{{}}l @{}}
a + b +       &\dotsb & + c = d  \\
a + b +       &\dotsb & + c = d  \\
              &\vdots           \\
aaaaaaa + b + &\dotsb & + c = d
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

(Notice the use of `\dotsb` in this case, to get the right dots.)