# How to put periods between a set of equations?

Tags: equations

Is there a better way to put points between a set of equations as follow:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&y_1=y_0+hf_0\\
&y_2=y_0+2hf_1\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
&y_n=y_{n-1}+2hf_{n-1}
\end{split}
\label{eq: stoer method 2}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: A quick comment, not related directly to your question but to the use of the `&` alignment points in a `split` environment: It's preferable to align the rows on a common element such as `=` instead of on the first character of each row. While the widths of `y_1`, `y_2`, and `y_n` happen to be fairly similar, the appearance of the system of equations risks becoming marred if you also have entries such as `y_[m-1}` to the left of the `=` symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&y_1=y_0+hf_0\\
&y_2=y_0+2hf_1\\
&\vdots\\
&y_n=y_{n-1}+2hf_{n-1}
\end{split}
\label{eq: stoer method 2}
\end{equation}

But rather

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
y_1=y_0+hf_0\\
y_2=y_0+2hf_1\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}\\
y_n=y_{n-1}+2hf_{n-1}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Certainly, the position of vertical dots can be changed.

Answer (score 7):

The [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package offers the macros `\vdotswithin` and `\shortvdotswithin` for just this purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
y_1&=y_0+hf_0\\
y_2&=y_0+2hf_1\\
&\vdotswithin{=}\\  %% note the "\\" row terminator
y_m&=y_{m-1}+2hf_{m-1}\\
\shortvdotswithin{=}  %% note: no row terminator
y_n&=y_{n-1}+2hf_{n-1}
\end{split}
\label{eq: stoer method 2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&y_1=y_0+hf_0\\
&y_2=y_0+2hf_1\\
\vdots\\    
&y_n=y_{n-1}+2hf_{n-1}
\end{split}
\label{eq: stoer method 2}
\end{equation}
```

Related question about the alignment of the vertical dots that you might want to look into: [Centering \vdots in a system of many equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/centering-vdots-in-a-system-of-many-equations)