# Centering \vdots in a system of modular equations

Tags: equations

I want to centering \vdots with \equiv in a system of modular equations. And I tried to use `mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\equiv}}` like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7650/centering-vdots-in-a-system-of-many-equations).
But XeLaTeX said

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                              \dimen@ii =\z@ \@tf@r \res...
l.238   \end{frame}
               
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

My full text:

```
\[
  \begin{cases}
    x \equiv a_1 &\pmod{m_1}\\
    \mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{\equiv}]{\vdots}}\\
    x \equiv a_n &\pmod{m_n}
  \end{cases}
 \]
```

And I tried to type `≡` manually, but XeLaTeX can't display it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use the mathtools package and it's `\vdotswithin{\equiv} ` macro

Comment: The reason your attempt does not work is that `\makebox` and `\widthof` works in text mode, and you are giving it something that require math mode

Answer (score 1):

Combine @daleif suggestion with the `empheq` package to emulate a `numcases` environment. 
You don't have to load `mathtools` as empheq does it for you. If you want only one number for the whole system, use `aligned` inside `equation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}%

\begin{document}     

\begin{align}[left = \empheqlbrace]%
    x &\equiv a_1\pmod{m_1}\\
    & \vdotswithin{\equiv}\notag \\
    x &\equiv a_n\pmod{m_n}
    \end{align}
    \vskip 1cm
    \begin{equation}[left = \empheqlbrace]
   \begin{aligned}%
    x &\equiv a_1\pmod{m_1}\\
    & \vdotswithin{\equiv}\\
    x &\equiv a_n\pmod{m_n}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And how can I shorten the gap between equations?

Comment: with the  optional argument to `\\`, say `\\[-4pt]`.

Comment: Can't use `\[-4pt]`. XeLaTeX said `Bad math environment deliter`.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, that was a typo: it's `\\[4pt]` (or as many pt as you please…).