# Aligning multiple binary operators

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

### Objective

I want to align the following:

```
expr_a1 <= expr_a2 <= expr_a3 \\
expr_b2 <= expr_b2 <= expr_b3 \\
```

Now, I want the `<=` to be aligned with each other; the `expr_*2` to be centered; the `expr_*1` to be right aligned, and the `expr_*3` to be left aligned

### What I have tried:

`\begin{flalign}`, `\begin{align}`

### Question:

Is this possible to do with `flalign`/`align`, or should I be looking into other packages in AmsMath, or other packages in LaTeX?

### Minimal Broken Example:

```
\begin{flalign}
a_1    & \leq &    a_2    & \leq &   a_3 \\
b_1    & \leq &    b_2    & \leq &   b_3 \\
\end{flalign}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4273/1410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to obtain the desired alignment - using an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{{}\leq{}}c@{{}\leq{}}l}
    a_1 a_1 a_1 & a_2         & a_3 a_3 a_3 \\[\jot]
    b_1         & b_2 b_2 b_2 & b_3
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The alignment for the relational operators is specified as the column separation, with the appropriate spacing (of a relational mathematical operator via `{}\leq{}` - the addition of an empty object on either side is important). `\jot` adds a little vertical space between the expressions, for presentation.

If you wish to have the expressions numbered, a little more work is required.

Comment: Apparently, I'm not allowed to accept the answer until 1 more minute has passed.

Comment: Why `\mathrel{\leq}`? As far as I know, `\leq` *is* a math relation. :)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I was overly cautious in my spacing... :)

Answer (score 6):

For multiple alignment points I would recommend the `alignat` environment:

[image]

Similar to the `align` environment, the `alignat` provides multiple `rl` alignments but without the spacing in between the pairs of `rl` equations.  The `&&` was necessary to make the following column `l`eft aligned (and skip past the `r`ight aligned column).

If you want to center a column you could use `\makebox{}{}` macro once you know the widest entry in the column:

[image]

---

### Code (left aligned column):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
a_1 a_1 a_1 & \le a_2         && \le a_3 a_3 a_3 \\
    b_1     & \le b_2 b_2 b_2 && \le b_3
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code (centered column):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\Widest}{b_2 b_2 b_2}%
\newcommand*{\Center}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\Widest$}]{$#1$}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
a_1 a_1 a_1 & \le \Center{a_2        } && \le a_3 a_3 a_3 \\
    b_1     & \le \Center{b_2 b_2 b_2} && \le b_3
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this does not centre the middle column of elements, as per the request.

Comment: @Werner: Didn't see that initially, so have provided an updated solution for that case.

Comment: This seems a more flexible solution than the others as each  line in the example can be given its own equation number if this is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a table structure?  I think something like this might work:

```
\begin {tabular} {r @{$\leq$} c @{$\leq$} l}
  $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ \\
  $b_1$ & $b_2$ & $b_3$
\end {tabular}
```