# Space between multiple columns in align* too large

Tags: align, multicolumn

I want an align* environment with two columns, to display two equality signs per line, both aligned to the corresponding equality signs in the other lines.

For example:

```
\begin{align*}
    a &= 1 + 2 + 3 &= 6 \\
    b &= 1 + 2     &= 3
\end{align*}
```

However, when I try this in LaTeX, I get the following output:

[image: Output]

I'd like to avoid the large space in front of =6 and =3. Does anybody know what is wrong with my code? I extracted the syntax from [wikibooks.org](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A). I also tried to add an additional & in the middle, but the result stays the same for me:

```
\begin{align*}
    a &= 1 + 2 + 3  &  &= 6 \\
    b &= 1 + 2      &  &= 3
\end{align*}
```

Comment: You can't align one set of equations in two different places. Just use `gather*`, remove all `&` and it'll be ok.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: relevant: [Aligning multiple binary operators](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63584/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alignat*` for aligning at 2 points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    a &= 1 + 2 + 3  &&= 6 \\
    b &= 1 + 2      &&= 3
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can, if you're willing to let your document to look disasterous :D

Comment: Thank you, Harish. Just what I was looking for. Actually, I had imagined that align* is designed to work as alignat* does.
@yo', what's wrong with that solution? I've introduced this method at several places in my documents and couldn't find any drawbacks. I use it for formular comments, too.

Comment: @Illuminat The empty space is **horrible**. I don't really think that by aligning the numbers, you increase the readability of the text. Unwanted space (horizontal or vertical) can only confuse people. As I said, I would typeset this as `\begin{gather*} a = 1+2+3 = 6, \\ b = 1+2 = 3. \end{gather*}`. Formular comments -- if you mean putting something on the right in parentheses in a series of equalities -- is what I call a "high-school style" and I don't consider it as good mathematical typography.