# Aligning texts side by side with equations in \align environment

Tags: align

I type equivalent equations using `\align` environment and so, I have to write the word "or" besides the second, third and fourth equations. I want to align the word "or" in the three lines. I use

```
\begin{align*}
\phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \right) 
&=  \phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j}\circ\pi  \right)(e)t_{j}(p)\right), 
\\
\text{or}\qquad \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)\phi(t_{j}(e)) 
&=  \sum_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)\phi(t_{j}(p)),
 \\
 \text{or}\qquad  \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j}) 
 &= \sum_{j=1}^{r}  \left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
 \\
 \text{or}\qquad \left(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j}  \right) 
  &= \left(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}\left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)e_{j} \right).
 \end{align*}
```

Here is what this produces

[image]

I hope that my question is clear.

Comment: Can you make your code fragment compilable?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean !

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use another alignment point; I show two ways, one with `align`, the other one with `alignat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&&          \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \biggr) 
            &= \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr), 
\\
&\text{or}& \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)\phi(t_{j}(e)) 
            &=  \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)\phi(t_{j}(p)),
\\
&\text{or}& \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j}) 
            &= \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
\\
&\text{or}& \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j}  \biggr) 
            &= \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)e_{j} \biggr).
\end{align*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&\qquad    \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \biggr) 
            &= \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr), 
\\
&\text{or}& \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)\phi(t_{j}(e)) 
            &=  \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)\phi(t_{j}(p)),
\\
&\text{or}& \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j}) 
            &= \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
\\
&\text{or}& \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j}  \biggr) 
            &= \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)e_{j} \biggr).
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the outer `\left(` and `\right)` should better be `\biggl(` and `\biggr). Add`\,`after`\biggl(`in order not to hit the subscript. The inner`\left`and`\right` are wrong.

[image]

An alternative without alignment at the equals signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 & \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \biggr)
           = \phi\biggl(\,\sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr),
\\
\text{or}\quad
 & \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)\phi(t_{j}(e))
   =  \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)\phi(t_{j}(p)),
\\
\text{or}\quad
 & \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j})
   = \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
\\
\text{or}\quad
 & \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j}  \biggr)
   = \biggl(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r} (b^{j}\circ\pi)(e)e_{j} \biggr).
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is cool, but what does the parameter (2) refer to ?

Comment: @HusseinEid Within `alignat` you have to tell LaTeX how many pairs of right-left columns you want.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to do any special spacing, just add a couple of `&`s to each line
to take advantage of the fact that `align*` can handle multiple side-by-side
equations (or other components).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& &\phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \right) 
 &=  \phi\left(\sum_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j}\circ\pi  \right)(e)t_{j}(p)\right), 
\\
&\text{or} &\sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)\phi(t_{j}(e)) 
&=  \sum_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)\phi(t_{j}(p)),
 \\
& \text{or} & \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j}) 
 &= \sum_{j=1}^{r}  \left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
 \\
& \text{or} &\left(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j}  \right) 
  &= \left(p, \sum_{j=1}^{r}\left(b^{j}\circ\pi \right)(e)e_{j} \right).
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: This is fine, but I see that the horizontal gap between the word "or" and the equation on the same line is too much. Can this gab be decreased a little ?

Comment: @HusseinEid -- i was about to give a version with `alignat*`, but (as usual), egreg got there first.

Comment: I appreciate your help so. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `alignat`. I also propose a solution with the `\ArrowBetweenLines` command, from `mathtools`, which looks nicer, in my opinion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\OrBetweenLines{\ArrowBetweenLines[\text{or}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & & ϕ\biggl(∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p) \biggr)
  &= ϕ\biggl(∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr),
  \\
    & \text{or} & ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)ϕ(t_{j}(e))
  &= ∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)ϕ(t_{j}(p)),
  \\
    & \text{or} & ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j})
  &= ∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
  \\
    & \text{or}\quad & \biggl(p, ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j} \biggr)
  &= \biggl(p, ∑_{j=1}^{r}\left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)e_{j} \biggr).
\end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & & ϕ\biggl(∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr)
  &= ϕ\biggl(∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)t_{j}(p)\biggr),
  \\
  \OrBetweenLines
    & & ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)ϕ(t_{j}(e))
  &= ∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)ϕ(t_{j}(p)),
  \\
  \OrBetweenLines
    & & ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)(p,e_{j})
  &= ∑_{j=1}^{r} \left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)(p,e_{j}) ,
  \\
  \OrBetweenLines
    & & \biggl(p, ∑_{j=1}^{r}c^{j}(e)e_{j} \biggr)
  &= \biggl(p, ∑_{j=1}^{r}\left(b^{j} ∘ \pi \right)(e)e_{j} \biggr).
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about using an array environment, such as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63579/aligning-multiple-binary-operators). You could put & after each or as well as after =

Comment: Your link is not inserted correctly...