# Align a wall of equations

Tags: align

I have a wall of equations in the format:
y = x^2 = 9

So basically, it's the variable part, the equation part and the answer part. I want these to be in three columns that are all aligned. So my wall of equations looks like this:

```
Using this formula $C_{in} = \frac{C_{out}g_i}{\hat{f}}$
\[ C_{in-nand3} = \frac{30 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 11.0344 \rightarrow \frac{11.0344}{2.75} = 4.0125  \]
\[ C_{in-nand2} = \frac{6.153 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.263 \rightarrow \frac{2.263}{2.75} = .8229  \]
\[ C_{in-nand1} = \frac{5.514 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.0279 \rightarrow \frac{2.0279}{2.75} = .7374  \]
```

There's more but you get the idea. I looked at other posts that suggested I put a

```
\begin{align}
\end{align}
```

Around the whole thing, I did that but when I tried to compile in TexStudio it spat out this list of errors:

[image]

I have no idea what it is asking about. Does anyone know how I can achieve the alignment that I want?

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities) which provides a solution to your problem.

Comment: The `align` environment puts its material into display-math mode automatically. Thus, remove the `\]` and `\[` items, and be sure to terminate all but the very last line with a \\ (double backslash) directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `align` environment you should use `&` like this:

```
\begin{align}
    C_{in-nand3} & = \frac{30 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 11.0344 \rightarrow \frac{11.0344}{2.75} = 4.0125 \\
    C_{in-nand2} & = \frac{6.153 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.263 \rightarrow \frac{2.263}{2.75} = .8229 \\
    C_{in-nand1} & = \frac{5.514 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.0279 \rightarrow \frac{2.0279}{2.75} = .7374
\end{align}
```

This will align all equations.

Comment: okay now I have: `\begin{align}
Using this formula $C_{in} = \frac{C_{out}g_i}{\hat{f}}$:
 C_{in-nand3} & = \frac{5.493 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.02 \rightarrow \frac{2.02}{2.75} = .735  \ C_{in-nand2} & = \frac{(2.02 + 12.97) * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 5.514 \rightarrow \frac{5.514}{2.75} = 2.005  \ C_{in-nand1} & = \frac{5.514 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.0279 \rightarrow \frac{2.0279}{2.75} = .7374 
\end{align}` but that gives me these errors http://i.stack.imgur.com/WWPSE.jpg

Comment: `C_\textnormal{in-nand3}` will avoid typesetting the subscript in math font with the hyphen becoming a minus sign.

Comment: @Richard: Place this: `Using this formula $C_{in} = \frac{C_{out}g_i}{\hat{f}}$:` before the `\begin{align}`.

Comment: since the original question used `\[...\]`, i'd guess that no equation numbers are wanted, so `align*` would seem a better choice of environment.

Comment: Okay nvm, I fixed it now! I just had an empty space after `\begin{align}` and the first equation, texstudio didn't like that.