# Aligning parts of equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

So this is a continuation of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105710/align-a-wall-of-equations) but I didn't know if I should edit that post and ask a new question or just post a new question entirely. Anyway, I have this bit of latex:

```
\begin{align*}
    C_{in-nand3} & = \frac{5.493 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.02 \rightarrow & \frac{2.02}{2.75} = .735  \\
    C_{in-nand2} & = \frac{(2.02 + 12.97) * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 5.514 \rightarrow & \frac{5.514}{2.75} = 2.005  \\
    C_{in-nand1} & = \frac{5.514 * 1.21739}{3.3098} = 2.0279 \rightarrow & \frac{2.0279}{2.75} = .7374 
\end{align*}
```

And that gives me:
[image]

But what I really want is the answers to the first equation to be centered down a middle column. So for example, I want `=2.02->` to be shifted to the right and aligned with all the following values such as `=5.514->` down a column. I tried adding a `&` before the `=2.02` but that gave me:
[image]

Which is not what I want, that is shifted waaay too much.

Comment: Have you tried using \begin{equation}...\end{equation}?

Comment: @cryptic0 do I have to wrap \begin{equation}...\end{equation} around every single line? Because I just posted 3 lines of equations, it's actually much more than that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps this is closer to what you want?

[image: output of following code example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{5}
    C_{in-nand3} & = \frac{5.493 * 1.21739}{3.3098} && = 2.02 \rightarrow{} & \frac{2.02}{2.75} & = .735  \\
    C_{in-nand2} & = \frac{(2.02 + 12.97) * 1.21739}{3.3098} && = 5.514 \rightarrow{} & \frac{5.514}{2.75} & = 2.005  \\
    C_{in-nand1} & = \frac{5.514 * 1.21739}{3.3098} && = 2.0279 \rightarrow{} & \frac{2.0279}{2.75} & = .7374 
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

**edit:** the question [Aligning equations with text with alignat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat) addresses a similar problem.

Comment: Maybe you could mention a link to the question [Aligning equations with text with alignat](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning-equations-with-text-with-alignat) and I'll delete my almost identical answer ?

Comment: @VincentNivoliers -- done.  thanks for the suggestion.