# Aligning multiple inequality symbols

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat

I have a question about how to align multiple symbols for a set of inequalities to make it look clean. This is what I have at the moment:

```
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(a)| &< f(a) \\
-f(a) < f(x) - f(a) &< f(a) \\
-f(a) + f(a) < f(x) &< f(a) + f(a) \\
0 < f(x) &< 2f(a) \\
\implies f(x) &> 0.
\end{align*}
```

Which only aligns the right inequality signs with each other: [image]

What I would like to accomplish is similar to the result one might get when using the alignat environment. Ideally, I would like to essentially create 3 columns with the inequality signs acting as separators - but I would like the middle column to be center justified.

Also note that the top row only has one inequality sign - I would like that to be aligned with all the signs on the right. How might I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Align two inequalities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4273/5764)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use `alignat`?

Comment: It doesn't center the middle column... Was wondering if there is a clean way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use ow `array` it is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{rcccl}
                & ~ & f(x)-f(a)|  & < & f(a) \\
-f(a)           & < & f(x) - f(a) & < & f(a) \\
-f(a) + f(a)    & < & f(x)        & < & f(a) + f(a) \\
0               & < & f(x)        & < & 2f(a) \\
                & ~ &\implies f(x)& > & 0
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it is certainly prettier than what I have. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `alignat` and the `eqparbox` package. I took the opportunity do define an `\eqmathbox` command: its optional argument is a tag (`M` by default), and its mandatory argument is in mathmode, display style. All `\eqmathbox`es sharing the same tag will have their contents centred in a box of width the largest contents width. I also  defined an `\abs` command, which adds an implicit pair of `\left\lvert … \right\rvert` around its argument in its starred version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
              & \phantom{{}<{}} & \eqmathbox{\abs{ f(x)-f(a)}} & < f(a) \\
  -f(a) & < & \eqmathbox{f(x)-f(a)} & < f(a) \\%
  -f(a) + f(a) & < & \eqmathbox{f(x)} & < f(a) + f(a) \\
  0 & < & \eqmathbox{f(x)} & < 2f(a) \\
               & & \implies f(x) & > 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]