# Align two inequalities -- newer version

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat

I know the question has already been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4273/align-two-inequalities) but the last answer is from more than 9 years ago. Is there a simple way to align two (in)equalities and center the middle "column" ?  I thought of using `array` but the font is smaller, it doesn't number the equations and so on.

Here is my code with `align`

```latex
\begin{align}
0 &< a_k &\leq \frac{1}{k}\\
\lim_{k \to \infty} 0 &< \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k &\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Nothing changes in last ten years. The second example in @Werner answer in given link is still (only) way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy with `alignat` and `eqparbox`, which defines tagged boxes – all boxes sharing the same tag has as width the widest natural width of them.

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
0 &< & \eqmathbox{a_k} & \leq \frac{1}{k}\\
\lim_{k \to \infty} 0 &< {}&\eqmathbox{ \smashoperator{\lim_{k \to \infty}} a_k} &\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k}
\end{alignat}


\begin{alignat}{3}
0 &<{} & & a_k \leq{} & &\frac{1}{k}\\
\lim_{k \to \infty} 0 &< {}& \smashoperator{\lim_{k \to \infty}}{} & a_k \leq{} & \lim_{k \to \infty}{} & \frac{1}{k}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how would I proceed if I wanted to align the the a_k and 1/k too ? It would be uncentered but I'm curious.

Comment: You mean a_k would no more be centred in the middle column?

Comment: Yes, so that it looks like just the limit are added. Why did you add {} and  \le{} ?

Comment: \smashoperator neutralises the width of the subscript under  lim, when it is larger , so the it does not increase the spacing with the surrounding formulæ. For your new requirement, let me think a moment, but it will make more columns.

Comment: Please see my edit: I've added another example for your second question. The `{}` added after `\leq`is because without it, ans the ampersand is just after this sign, there is no spacing after.